# Applying a dynamic attribute based directive to a div element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using Angular 1.4.x version and I've been trying this for a while without success. I want to apply a dynamic attribute to a div element.

For ex.,

```
<div {{vm.dynamicAttributeName}}>...</div>
```

Un-fortunately this is not working. I checked `ng-attr` but that's for a different purpose.

Finally I created a custom directive to accomplish that after some googling. Though it works I'm not sure whether it's the right approach. Can someone please shed some light on this. Is there a better easier way to achieve this?

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    function dynamicDirective($compile, $parse) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            compile: function (el, attrs) {
                return function (scope) {
                    if (attrs.dynamicDir !== undefined) {
                        el.attr(attrs.dirName, "");
                        el.removeAttr('dynamic-dir');
                        el.removeAttr('dir-name');
                    }

                    $compile(el)(scope);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    dynamicDirective.$inject = ['$compile', '$parse'];
    module.exports = dynamicDirective;
})();

<div dynamic-dir dir-name="vm.dynamicAttributeName"></div>
```

Comment: Do you want to add dynamicly angular directive or just html attr ?

Comment: dynamicly angular directive